# display buttons in a single row in div slot footer

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Here is the screenshot shows one toggle checkbox and two buttons on right right, is that possible to make it checkbox keep it on left and buttons on the right but make it in a single row instead of two rows?

html:

```
<div slot="footer" >
        <lightning-input type="toggle" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon" onchange={selectall}></lightning-input>

        <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" class="slds-m-right_medium" onclick={closeQuickAction}>
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your footer as a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) via [`slds-grid`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) class, then add two div as the two columns and put in left (first) one the toggle and in the right one the buttons.
Since buttons are inline elements, you can manage their alignment via `slds-text-align_right` class.

```
<div slot="footer" class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-input type="toggle" label="Select all" variant="label-hidden" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon" onchange={selectall}></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-text-align_right">
        <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" class="slds-m-right_medium" onclick={closeQuickAction}> </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way, for [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) the `label` attribute is required. If you don't want to display a label, specify the `variant="label-hidden"` attribute.
The label attribute creates an HTML  element for your input component. Using the label-hidden variant, it will be hidden from view while it will remain available to assistive technology.

Comment: but I don't see any errors in the dev console when I don't define the label

Comment: @NickKahn Using the mini playground available in the documentation page I get an [error](https://imgur.com/XTxjvDl) in the dev console. In the Specification tab it's the only attribut marked as required.

Comment: @NickKahn you can try to remove the label attribute [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/CGbNt2NIkI8ECwMrqZZr).